# How can monogoimport.exe skip first column and header line in csv?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I need to import csv file into mongoDB.
The csv file contain 3 columns, but I want to import only 2 columns and skip the first column and the headers line.

If I have :

```
id, firstName, lastName  
1, Joe,  Williams
```

How can I import only the firstName and lastName columns and skip the id column and the headers line?
I don't want to change the csv itself.
I am using script for the import:

```
"...\mongoimport.exe" --host  __  --username __  --authenticationDatabase ___ --password __ --db __ --collection __--headerline --file MyCsv.csv --type csv --maintainInsertionOrder
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 mongoimport /fields:firstName, lastName    ///***/// add your optons here
```

> mongoimport.exe --help

```
input options:
  /f, /fields:<field>[,<field>]*                  comma separated list of field
                                                  names, e.g. -f name,age
      /fieldFile:<filename>                       file with field names - 1 per
                                                  line
      /file:<filename>                            file to import from; if not
                                                  specified, stdin is used
      /headerline                                 use first line in input
                                                  source as the field list (CSV
                                                  and TSV only)
      /jsonArray                                  treat input source as a JSON
                                                  array
      /type:<type>                                input format to import: json,
                                                  csv, or tsv (defaults to
                                                  'json')
```

Comment: Thank for the replay. Can I skip the header line too?

Comment: @Shir no, as mongo need to match field name to value